# At what point does the upload occur in an html form?

Tags: html, forms

Okay, so I've been handed this code (surrounding code is standard head/body framework and script defining "ConvertPPT2HTML()"):

```
<h1>Powerpoint Upload</h1>
<form id="form2"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="test_ppt_uploader.php" method="POST">
    <table border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td ><b>Select File:</b> </td>
        <td>
        <input type=hidden name="pptfilename" id="pptfilename" value="">
        <input type=hidden name="tempfilename" id="tempfilename" value="">
        <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id=upload  size=25 >
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" name=sub value="Upload File"  onclick=" return ConvertPPT2HTML();"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

The requirements are to:

- Stop it from uploading any files from the client to the server
- Keep it doing the ConvertPPT2HTML work (basically using AJAX to open the actual ppt file at the supplied path, saving a temp copy and a copy as html and then zipping it up for later upload)

The actual file is available in the php script after submit is hit, so my initial take was to remove:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="test_ppt_uploader.php" method="POST">
```

Which does the job. But I'm not sure if the file is still being uploaded and discarded, or if it's not being uploaded at all.

I do want to keep the file widget around for browsing the file system, I just want to ensure it merely gives you a path, not an uploaded file.

So the specific question is *Does the code below still upload anything?*

```
<h1>Powerpoint Converter</h1>
<form id="form2">
    <table border="0" >
      <tr>
        <td ><b>Select File TWJC:</b> </td>
        <td>
        <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id=upload  size=25 >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name=sub value="Upload File"  onclick=" return ConvertPPT2HTML();">
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if `ConvertPPT2HTML()` returns `true` then your form will still upload the PPT to the server.  The form's `action` attribute defaults to the current URL.

You can use the "Network" tab in Chrome or IE's developer tools to watch the form submission.

Comment: Cool, good thing I checked. Two questions: Does it only upload when the submit is pressed, and How do I *stop* it doing the upload? `input type='button'`?

Comment: @deworde: It uploads when there is an `input type="file"` in a form that is posted, so removing the `input` or keeping the form from being posted would stop the upload.

Comment: I would try deleting the `<FORM>` tag completely, and then change `<input type="submit"` to `<input type="button"`

Comment: I'd mark this as accepted if there was more info about the Network tab and how to stop the file being uploaded. Looking at the network tab right now, all I see is a GET with the file path in.